# Getting image from memory cache

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

My task is to get some images which are dynamically loaded, decrypted on the client side using javascript and placed an in-memory cache. Unfortunately, I didn't find any documentation that will help me to get those pictures either from memory cache or browser. I can find it in chrome dev-tools though

[chrome devtools screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H3GL.png)

I am using chromedriver and c# but can use another web driver.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot, images loaded from memory cache are inline images. Identifier for such images is that it starts with "data:image". Such images are not hosted or stored at any place, instead their url represents their content, thus you can store the complete url of the resource to make use of it later.

Comment: where can I find that URL?

Comment: Using chromedriver?